# User controlled presentation of data in widgets on a dashboard app - Best Practices?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

Consider a very simple dashboard application in Django. It has 2 models:

1. Page
2. Widget

Naturally, Page and Widget have a ManyToMany relationship.

Like any good dashboard implementation, the designers can change 3 things in a widget:

1. Data source that drives the widget
2. Placement of widget on the Page
3. Presentation of Data inside a widget

The Data is specified using a URL field in the Widget and is being served by a REST API  based on Django REST Framework with the django-filter backend.

The Placement on the Page is catered using the excellent Gridster.

This leaves the Presentation part. I have two possible solutions:

1. Attach a template TextField with the Widget. Data will be fetched from web services in JSON format and rendered according to the template (handlebars) defined in Widget on the client side.
2. Pass the template name as query string in the URL to the REST API and render the Data using the user-specified template.

Now that the context is clearly defined (hopefully), following are my questions:

1. Is there any way I can choose the first solution and still be able to use the automatic forms generated by the DRF Serializers?
2. If not, and I choose the second solution, are there any potential pit-falls regarding security, code maintenance, code quality, testing and the like? Why have I not seen anyone else doing this i.e. letting the user select the template via query string?
3. Is there any other solution that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first options seems most promising: fetch the data as JSON and insert it into templates on the client. All good.

So can you do that "and still be able to use the automatic forms generated by the DRF Serializers"? — Short answer, it depends what you mean by "automatic forms".

Serializers take a data dictionary, validate it and (for `ModelSerializer` subclasses) convert it into a (model) object instance for you. If by "automatic forms" you mean will you still be able to this validation behaviour, then the answer is yes. Create your JSON payload on the client and send an appropriate HTTP request to the API. Django Rest Framework's Serializers will work as expected.

If (though) by "automatic forms" you mean will you still be able to use the HTML forms that DRF provides in its web broweasble API, then the answer is no. The browseable API is built around an HTML renderer returning entire web pages. These include a pretty-printed representation of the JSON you'll be using as well as the web-forms that, on this assumption, you're interested in.

If you go this route you'll need to generate the forms on the client, using whatever model, view, template and binding features your chosen library (libraries?) offer(s).

I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I discovered and ended up using an amazing project that sort of offers the best of both worlds! Do check out [django-remote-forms](https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms). [Here](http://fr.slideshare.net/tarequeh/django-forms-in-a-web-api-world) are the slides from djangocon US 2012. Maybe it will be of use to you or anyone else in a future project..